# Sequence in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Converting below SQL Server procedures and tables to store and generate sequence to postgresql.

Can anyone guide how to do this in Postgres (via table and this function) and not via sequence or nextval or currval

Sequence table

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'testtable')                                
    CREATE TABLE dbo.testtable(Sequence int NOT NULL )                              
go                              
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM testtable)                             
    INSERT INTO testtable VALUES (-2147483648)                              
go
```

Sequence generating proc

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_proc                                              
AS                                              
SET NOCOUNT ON                                              
DECLARE @iReturn int                                                
BEGIN TRANSACTION                                               
    SELECT @iReturn = Sequence FROM schema.test (TABLOCKX) -- set exclusive table lock                                          
    UPDATE schema.test SET Sequence = ( Sequence + 1 )                                          
COMMIT TRANSACTION                                              
SELECT @iReturn                                             
RETURN @iReturn                                                 
go                                              
grant execute on schema.test to public                                              
go
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a sequence? That's the only scalable and efficient way to generate unique numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** using a sequence is the only scalable and efficient way to generate unique numbers.

---

Having said that, it is possible to implement your own sequence generator. The only situation where makes any sense is, if you are required to generate gapless numbers. If you do not have such a requirement, use a sequence.

You need one table that stores the values of the sequences. I usually use one table with a row for each "generator" that avoids costly table locks.

```
create table seq_generator
(
   entity     varchar(30)            not null primary key,
   seq_value  integer      default 0 not null 
);

insert into seq_generator (entity) values ('testsequence');
```

Then create a function to increment the sequence value:

```
create or replace function next_value(p_entity varchar)
  returns integer
as
$$
  update seq_generator 
     set seq_value = seq_value + 1
  where entity = lower(p_entity)
  returning seq_value;
$$
language sql;
```

To obtain the next sequence value, e.g. inside an insert:

```
insert into some_table 
  (id, ...)
values 
  (next_value('testsequence'), ...);
```

Or make it a default value:

```
create table some_table
(
  id integer not null primary key default next_value('testsequence'),
  ...
);
```

The UPDATE increments and locks the row in a single statement returning the new value for the sequence. If the calling transaction commits, the update to `seq_generator` will also be committed. If the calling transaction rolls back, the update will roll back as well.

If a second transaction calls `next_value()` for the same entity, it has to wait until the first transaction commits or rolls back.

So access to the generator is serialized through this function. Only one transaction at a time can do that.

If you need a second gapless sequence, just insert a new row in the `seq_generator' table.

---

This will **seriously** affect performance when you use in an environment that does a lot of concurrent inserts.

The **only** reason that would justify this is a legal requirement to have a gapless number. In every other case you should really, really use a native Postgres sequence.